# Compiled & Deployed Smart Contract via Remix, can't "Verify and Publish" on Etherscan.io

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, nft

Good morning, I've created an NFT and deployed my smart contract to main network yesterday after compiling it in Remix. I followed the exact same process I did for testnet, which worked perfectly and allowed me to verify/publish, but is not working on main.

[image]

It says unable to generate ocntract ByteCode and ABI -- which I didn't have any for testnet, I left them blank and completed successfully.

Then the error looks like it's looking for a specific code seen below in the screenshot, and that code is also shown from my contract. So I'm confused what the issue is and would love any guidance.

My selected options were:

```
single file
0.7.0 compiler
Not optimized
Solidity
```

If I don't verify it, that means I can't interact with the contract right on etherscan.io right? I would have to use Remix or something else?

Comment: What's the source code? What's the license? Are you sure the compiler configuration is correct? What were the constructor parameters? In most cases the problem is that some of the parameters were wrong.

Comment: @Ismael Hi, thanks. Compiler: 0.7.0+commit.9e61f92b, Language: Solidity, EVM Version: compiler default, License: MIT, no configurations. I compiled it, then I deployed it. Here is the etherscan: https://etherscan.io/address/0xb9bc754225c6e1f5be98c937d3b9b80e49e82057

Comment: I was able to verify it on testnet quite a few times.

Comment: What's the testnet version? What's the source code? Are you sure you used solc 0.7.0?